# Segmentation fault when memset struct array in c

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct, memset

I am trying to empty all data in the struct array.

but it turns out to be segmentation fault.
Can someone please help me.

Struct

```
struct entry
{
   char  user;
    char  name[9];
    char  extension[4];
    short blockcount;
    short block[8];
};
struct entry directory[128];
```

main()

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
{
      memset(&directory[i], 0, sizeof(directory));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change

```
memset(&directory[i], 0, sizeof(directory));
```

to

```
memset(&directory[i], 0, sizeof(struct entry));
```

as you want to memset single element of array of structure

To memset entire arry you can also use

```
memset(directory, 0, sizeof(directory));// single statement, no need to loop all elements
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought it was that simple

Comment: `sizeof(directory[0])` would also work in the same way. To keep it as similar to what you asked in the question.